# html Background changes with BxSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to have it such that, when i change my image, the background in my html changes as well. Also, how can i make the slider transparent, so it will not show the white part (see image). Thanks for any help/advice given:)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row vertical-align">

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12, left-col"> 
            <p><span id="prev"></span></p>      
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" class="content">
          <!--       GALLERY -->
                <ul class="bxslider">
                    <li data-slide-index="0"><img src="assets/slides/image1.jpg"></li>
                    <li data-slide-index="1"><img src="assets/slides/image2.jpg"></li>
                    <li data-slide-index="2"><img src="assets/slides/image3.jpg"></li>
                </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12, right-col">
            <p><span id="next"></span></p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            pager:false,
            adaptiveHeight:true,
            slideWidth:900,
            nextSelector: '#next',
            prevSelector: '#prev',
            nextText: 'NEXT',
            prevText: 'PREV'
        });
    });

</script>

<script>
 bxSlider.$On($bxSlider$.$EVT_PARK, function (slideIndex, fromeIndex) {
        if (slideIndex == 0) {
            $('body').css("green")
        }
        else if (slideIndex == 1) {
            //change container background color to blue
        }
    });
 </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution the I found is to change bxslider css (the steps are for **rails** user) .

step 1: find the bxslider css file.

run `bundle show bxslider`

you should get as a result the location (in my case: `/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bxslider-rails-4.2.5.1`)

step 2: open the bxslider css file.

with nano or any other editor 
    $ cd /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bxslider-rails-4.2.5.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
    $ nano bxslider.css.scss

step 3: change bxslider css file.

commit all the line in and add `background:rgba(0,0,0,0);` in .bx-wrapper class under THEME (commit and not delete so you can change back easily) in my case it's start on line 38 (ver 4.2.5.1):

```
.bx-wrapper {
//  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
//  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
//  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
//  border: 5px solid #fff);
//  background: #fff;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

step 4 create new css file:

run

bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace

in your project folder

Edit:
step 5 don't forget change the file in production as well!!!

Answer (score 0):

To set the body to have a green background, do:

```
$('body').css( "background-color", "green" );
```

An alternative approach, using stylesheets, is to set an attribute on your body element like this:

```
$('body').attr("data-slide-index", slideIndex);
```

...and then have a CSS file with stuff like this:

```
body[data-slide-index=0] {   background-color: green; }
body[data-slide-index=1] {   background-color: blue; }
body[data-slide-index=2] {   background-color: yellow; }
```

etc.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I'm trying it but why do they say "Slide Index undefined"?

Comment: I've added the screenshot in the question above